# How to filter column based on a column filtered in another Table?

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL, I would appreciate your help in the below:

I would like to filter columns based on a column filtered in another Table

i.e

```
SELECT *
FROM TableX 
WHERE ColumnX IN (ColX distinct values of TableY, where ColumnZ in ('a','b',c'))
```

Comment: Tag the question with the database that you use.

Comment: You do you mean "distinct values"?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use join :

```
select x.*
from tablex x inner join 
     tabley y
     on y.colx = x.colx
where y.colz in ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

However, you can also use `exists` :

```
select x.*
from tablex x 
where exists (select 1 
              from tabley y 
              where y.colx = x.colx and y.colz in ('a', 'b', 'c')
             );
```

Comment: @AmrSabry . . . I recommend `exists`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableX 
where ColumnX in (select y.ColX from TableY as y where y.ColumnZ in ('a','b','c'))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax for what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM TableX 
WHERE ColumnX IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT ColX FROM TableY 
  WHERE ColumnZ IN ('a','b','c')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tableX 
where columnX in (
         select 
            colX 
         from tableY 
         where columnZ in ('a','b','c')
   )
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.